# Not able to Execute Selenium scripts using Jenkins with latest Firefox browser V59 & Gecko Driver

Tags: jenkins, geckodriver

I am currently using FF 59 , Gecko Driver V0.20.1, Windows 10 OS  & Eclipse with Maven. When using a batch or executing scripts via eclipse scripts run fine in Firefox but when i try to do the same via Jenkins i get this error. Same question have been asked before for Linux OS where solution says to use FireFox 57.0 Version. But i can't use that version and i need to use latest version to run my scripts. I am getting below error in Jenkins when trying to execute. Doesn't Jenkins support latest Gecko driver and Firefox version? Is there any solution to the issue. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
Error:

1523405456958   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-profile" "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\rust_mozprofile.NQCI0vvVeET7"

1523405460671   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828

#### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x46001C,name=PContent::Msg_PreferenceUpdate) Channel error: cannot send/recv

#### !!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2C0001,name=PBrowser::Msg_AsyncMessage) Channel error: cannot send/recv

JavaScript error: chrome://global/content/bindings/remote-browser.xml, line 44: NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIMessageSender.sendAsyncMessage]

Answer (score 1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\geckodriver.exe");

        final FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
        options.addPreference("browser.popups.showPopupBlocker", false);
        options.addPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only this line helped me:

```
options.addPreference("security.sandbox.content.level", 5);
```

Comment: How is that helpful? What is the rationale behind this?